# How to run a command with no-tty access, to run in admin privileges?

Tags: gksu, sudo

I would like to execute a command with administrative privileges, but do not have an access to the tty.

I tried to execute it with the `-A` option of the `sudo` command and setting the environment variable `SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/gksu`.

To do the same I ran the command as following

```
env SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/gksu sudo -A _root-privilage-cmd_
```

But I got the `gksu` window, which would not authenticate me...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the password prompt, why not simply run `gksu command`?

Otherwise, to avoid the password prompt, you need to tweak into `/etc/sudoers` file, to say that that command can be executed without a password (but also without a password you need to run it through gsku).

Comment: I want to run the _root-previlage-cmd_ from an application launched by normal user, but in the application I would like to run the _root-previlage-cmd_ which should get me the password prompt to authenticate the admin-previlages.